# getDownloadURL isn't inputting the link i need

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Trying to get the downloadUrl link and put it into the "profile/imageURL" node on database.

I'm new to firebase and android development, so i was reading through release notes etc on storage and noticed [in the notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) and found information on downloadUrl. I understand there are plenty of questions on this topic but it's hard to apply it to this code.

"Deprecated the getDownloadUrl() and getDownloadUrls() methods of the StorageMetadata class. Use StorageReference.getDownloadUrl() instead."

But i'm trying to pull the downloadUrl link not from the metadata stored in firebase storage

I can successfully upload the picture to firebase storage but when i put the downloadUrl into firebase DB into the node i want. it inputs "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@xxxxx"

```
final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            UserProfileRef.child("profile").child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUrl)
```

I have tried the following 2 codes, This code outputs the uri com.google.xxxx

```
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }
    if (requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are uploading image...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            loadingBar.show();


            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Image stored Successfully to the the storage...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                        UserProfileRef.child("profile").child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                    {
                                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                                        {
                                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                            startActivity(selfIntent);


                                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile image stored to firebase database successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error Occured..." + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured: Image can't be cropped, try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

This second code was tried with the help of other users questions and trying to solve it that way. Although i get an error on .setValue(downloadUrl)

```
protected void onActivityResult( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
    {
        Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

        CropImage.activity()
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(this);
    }
    if (requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {

            loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are uploading image...");
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
            loadingBar.show();


            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            final StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

            filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                            final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                        }
                    });

                    UserProfileRef.child("profile").child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUrl)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                                    {
                                        Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                        startActivity(selfIntent);


                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile image stored to firebase database successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error Occured..." + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error Occured: Image can't be cropped, try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            loadingBar.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `getDownloadUrl()` returns a `Task` that asynchronously gets the download URL from the server. When it has retrieved the download URL, it calls `onComplete`/`onSuccess`. This means the download URL value is only available inside the `onComplete`/`onSuccess` method. Any code that needs the download URL needs to be inside `onComplete`/`onSuccess`.

So something like:

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();
                UserProfileRef.child("profile").child("imageURL").setValue(downloadUrl)
                  .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(selfIntent);
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile image stored to firebase database successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error Occured..." + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

---

Now having the code inside the `onSuccess` is of course not going to be very reusable. So you may consider creating a custom callback interface as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list). But the interface will be quite similar to the `Task<Uri>` interface in the example above, so I'm not sure it is worth the effort.

---

For an example of how to still keep the code separate from the `onComplete` by having your own custom callback interface, see [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519).