# How to get URL from Firebase Storage and send it to database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload an image to Firebase Storage and after that send the URL of this image to Firebase Database. The Uri is correct, but when I try to set it on my object, the method singleDetection.setImage(imagePath) is setting nothing. Here is my code:

```
Bitmap image = detectedFaceItems.get(0).getImage();
        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
        StorageReference imagesRef = storageRef.child("2.jpg");

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        StorageTask<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> uploadTask = imagesRef.putBytes(data)
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to sent a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully sent a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        storageRef.child("2.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                //Doesn't work corretly
                                String imagePath = uri.toString();
                                singleDetection.setImage(imagePath);
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get an Uri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `singleDetection.setImage(imagePath)` is supposed to do. But if you `Log.i("URL", imagePath)`, what does that output in your logcat?

Comment: setImage just set string to object.
Log.i("URL", imagePath) and Log.i("URL", singleDetection.getImage()) inside the onSuccess method return url correctly, but Log.i("URL", singleDetection.getImae()) outside the onSuccess method returns nullPointerException.

Comment: That is expected: since the download URL is retrieved from the server, any code that needs to access the download URL needs to be inside `onSuccess` or be called from there. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127996/getdownloadurl-isnt-inputting-the-link-i-need/53128190#53128190

Answer (score 0):

You are uploading the image right, but your call to Firebase after successfully uploading the image using `storageRef.child("2.jpg").getDownloadUrl().` not that right as you already don't know the generated Uri which you can get from the snapshot that is returned back with the `taskSnapshot`.

So replace the below part of code:

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully sent a file", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        storageRef.child("2.jpg").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), uri.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Doesn't work corretly
                String imagePath = uri.toString();
                singleDetection.setImage(imagePath);
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed to get an Uri", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

With:

```
 .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

        // get upload url
        taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                String imagePath = String.valueOf(task.getResult());
                singleDetection.setImage(imagePath);

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Note: here you've uploaded the image itself, but don't upload its Uri, so you can to decide to upload it to firebase as you'd like.

Comment: Still the same problem. In onComplete method, the imagePath looks fine, but outside this method it's null.